# .NET Core Signalr R With Angular Client running in an iframe not authenticating

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I have an interesting problem where I have several SignalR hubs that are being communicated with via an Angular 10 client running inside of an iframe. I'm using Bearer tokens for authentication. 4 of the hubs can only be accessed via secure authentication. *These hubs are working correctly*. However, 2 hubs can be accessed either logged in or logged out. These 2 hubs are not indicating that they are authenticated. If I apply the Authorize attribute to the hub, then the hub correctly identifies itself as logged in, but not otherwise.

If I run this app outside of the iframe the two hubs indicate that they are authenticated correctly.

C# Code Services Startup

```
.AddOAuthValidation(options =>
{
    options.Events = new OAuthValidationEvents
    {
        OnRetrieveToken = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

            // If the request is for our hub...
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"))
            {
                // Read the token out of the query string
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
})
```

I'd like to note that the two hubs that don't require authorization do not get hit in the above code.

Client code

```js
private createConnection(path: string): ConnectionInfo {
        let connection: HubConnection;
        
        if (Globals.GetAccessToken()) {
            connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(this.apiUrl + '/Hubs/' + path, {
                    accessTokenFactory: Globals.GetAccessToken,
                })
                .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
                .build();
        } else {
            connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(this.apiUrl + '/Hubs/' + path)
                .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
                .build();
        }

        connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000 * 10; 
        connection.keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000;

        const conInfo: ConnectionInfo = {
            Connection: connection,
            ManuallyStopped: false,
            Name: path,
        };
        connection.onclose((error) => {
            if (!conInfo.ManuallyStopped) {
                console.log('Connection Error: ' + error);
                this.retryConnect(connection);
            }
        });

        return conInfo;
    }
```

Create connection gets called with the various hub paths. Globals.AccessToken *is not* null or undefined here and is in fact calling the factory method for getting the access token.

If I look at the negotiate and websocket calls, I do see the access token being provided in the headers and query string respectively. It does not appear to be different from running within the iframe or running outside of the iframe.

Is there something else I'm missing? I don't want to add the Authorize attribute because as I said it can be accessed while authenticated or not. But when the user is authenticated I want it to be marked as such.

Let me know if there is some other code you'd need to see.